# How to get webflux endpoint to serialize json with object name for each item

Tags: json, spring-boot, jackson, spring-webflux

I have a webflux endpoint that returns an array of items. I am trying to get it to add the object name to each item in the array as specified by @JsonRootName. I have tried configuring the object mapper using Jackson2ObjectMaper like so. I am using SpringBoot 2.4.4.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebFlux
public class JacksonConfig {

    @Bean
    public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer customizer() {
        return builder -> {
            builder.modules(new JavaTimeModule());
            builder.featuresToEnable(SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE);
            builder.featuresToEnable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);
            builder.indentOutput(true);
        };
    }
}
```

My endpoint is like the following:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/all/{id}", produces = "application/json")
public ResponseEntity<Flux<EventsMetaData>> getAllEventsByUser(@PathVariable String id) {
    return ResponseEntity.ok(eventsMetaDataService.getAllEventsByUserId(id));
}
```

Json response is:

```
[
    {
        "id": "342424234",
        "userid": "34324242",
        "eventId": null,
        "eventName": "Test 1",
        "eventDetails": null
    },
    {
        "id": "43435235",
        "userid": "34244242",
        "eventId": null,
        "eventName": "Test",
        "eventDetails": null
    }
]
```

Expected output:

```
[
   Event: {
        "id": "342424234",
        "userid": "34324242",
        "eventId": null,
        "eventName": "Test 1",
        "eventDetails": null
    },
    Event: {
        "id": "43435235",
        "userid": "34244242",
        "eventId": null,
        "eventName": "Test",
        "eventDetails": null
    }
]
```

However I am not getting the root object when my object is annotated with @JsonRootName

```
@JsonRootName(value = "Event")
public class Event {
```

Any suggestions most welcome.

Edit:
After having removed @EnableWebFlux from the configuration, it gives me a root wrapping value but still not as it should using a List:

```
{
    "List": [
        {
            "id": "610bd71077cfcd2ee941217c",
            "eventName": "Test",
            "eventDetails": null,
            "eventDateTime": null,
            "eventLink": null
        }
    ]
}
```

However a single object respects the wrapper like so:

```
{
    "event": {
        "id": "610bd71077cfcd2ee941217c",
        "eventName": "Test",
        "eventDetails": null,
        "eventDateTime": null,
        "eventLink": null
    }
}
```

Link to replicar project https://gitlab.com/dmbeer/so-68651608 even if the json structure is wrong the test List should not be there.

Comment: I know this is old now, and I might be missing something something, but your expected output is not valid JSON: arrays don’t have keys, and duplicate keys are not allowed in maps (also keys should be wrapped with quotes).

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to configure `Bean` like this.

```
@Configuration
public class ApplicaitonConfiguration {

    @Bean
    ObjectMapper objectMapper() {

        var mapper = JsonMapper.builder().addModules(new JavaTimeModule()).build();

        // Enable your features...

        return mapper;
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried this and no luck still the same output. It seems the RestController is not using the configured ObjectMapper

Comment: It is not working like the way your are expecting because what you want is not even a valid JSON.

Comment: please see edited question, the wrapper should not show List but event as a single item does. And why When I remove @EnableWebFlux does it work

Comment: Since I cannot see your whole codebase it’s hard to say why removing that EnableWebFlux works. As for JSON your expected output is not even a valid JSON.

Comment: I have added a link to a replicar project with the same problem. Even if the json structure is wrong the text List should not be there.

Comment: You are getting List because you enabled that feature in your Jackson config. I suggest you to look at Jackson documentation.